# Generate mod_rewrite.so

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, apache2

I've compiled apache2 with the command  ..

**./configure --enable-so --enable-module=rewrite**

I can not find the file
 mod_rewrite.so

what i need to do?
what's wrong?
sorry for my English.

thanks in advance

Comment: Have you also run the command 'make' once the ./configure command is done?

Comment: yes, i do, the problem is i don't found mod_rewrite.so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the compilation step went OK, you should be able to find mod_rewrite.so in your system as follows:

```
updatedb && locate mod_rewrite.so
```

or you can also use find:

```
find / -name mod_rewrite.so
```